# Распознавание голоса Web Kit Speech Recognition не работает

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, я добавил на сайт технологию Web Kit Speech Recognition API, эта технология способна распознавать голос. Мой сайт находится на локальном сервере, но браузер не дает доступа к микрофону, подскажите пожалуйста из-за чего это, и как это исправить

```js
var recognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
recognizer.interimResults = true;
recognizer.lang = 'ru-Ru';
recognizer.onresult = function (event) {
  var result = event.results[event.resultIndex];
  if (result.isFinal) {
     alert('Вы сказали: ' + result[0].transcript);
  }
}
recognizer.start();
```

Comment: a в самом браузере настройках смотрел?

Comment: Да, должен спрашивать разрешение, но упорно этого не делает

Comment: В коде ошибок нет

Comment: Пробовали руками поставить разрешение?

Comment: Да, всё, что мог в настройках разрешил

Comment: Пишет, что доступ к микрофону на этой странице заблокирован, хотя в настройках стоит спрашивать

Comment: Андрей, не помню статью, читал давно, помимо  настроек в браузере, сайт сам должен попросить разрешения.  у тебя просит?

Comment: Нет, можете помочь, скинуть ссылочку, или уже готовое решение?

Comment: Я буду вам очень признателен

Comment: SOS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Я тоже пробовал с сервера, не получилось. Нужен сервер с https. Ну или открывайте в виде файла, так работает, но нужно давать разрешение перед каждой "прослушкой" (если их несколько).